# Why isn't my insert statement executing into my database?

Tags: php, html, sql, sqlite

I am a beginner at working with HTML and PHP with SQLite3. I can't find a solution on the web and When I am executing a insert statement, it is not inserted.

Any tips would be helpful to resolve this issue. updateC is a radio button entry from a different HTML file.

```
if($updateC == 'Insert') {
      $sql = "INSERT INTO MANGA_BOOK (Title,Author,Genre,ISBN_number,Age_rating,Language,Book_review,Price)
              VALUES ('$Btitle', '$BAuthor', '$BGenre', '$BISBN', '$age', '$lan', '$bookRev', '$pr')";
      $enterInto = $db->exec($sql);

      $sql2 = "INSERT INTO SELLS (M_ISBN, S_ID, Copies) VALUES ('$BISBN', '$storeNum', '$cop')";
      $enterInto2 = $db->exec($sql2);
    } 

    $rowCount = $db->querySingle("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SELLS");
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Title, Author, ISBN_number, Copies, S_ID
            FROM MANGA_BOOK 
            NATURAL JOIN SELLS
            ORDER BY S_ID";
    $results = $db->query($sql);

    if($rowCount > 0) {
      echo '<table> <tr>';
      echo '<th>Title</th>';
      echo '<th>Author</th>';
      echo '<th>ISBN_number</th>';
      echo '<th>Copies</th>';
      echo '<th>S_ID</th>';
      echo '</tr>';

      while($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
        echo '<tr>', '<td>', $row["Title"], '</td>',
        '<td>', $row["Author"], '</td>',
        '<td>', $row["ISBN_number"], '</td>',
        '<td>', $row["Copies"], '</td>',
        '<td>', $row["S_ID"], '</td>', '</tr>';
      }
      echo '</table>';
    } else {
      echo "Error in fetching database";
    }
```

Comment: IMO the answer to this question cannot be known to the reader. Which insert isn't working? How do you know? Program simply assumes success. It doesn't interrogate any return values (eg the `exec` calls). Is it failing "silently" because of [error reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) settings? And i'd be remiss if I didn't encourage you to use [prepared queries](https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.prepare.php) to prevent the calamity of sql injection.

Comment: We have ran it, but it doesn't cause any errors but when we view our database, the data we entered didn't appear. Whenever we try to insert into our data, we would print out the contents of that table, but noticed that there wasn't anything we inserted into the table.